# How to run a mixed ANOVA on R

Tags: r, dataset, anova, mixed

I am trying to code a mixed ANOVA on R but I'm very confused about how to do this.

R keeps saying I am missing data even though the dataset is full. I'm also not sure if the columns are right.

My dataset:

One column with participants individual codes.

One column with the groups participants are in, coded 1 and 2 (should be my between factor?).

One column with data scores on test 1.

One column with data scores on test 2.

The test 1 and test 2 scores are my within factor.

My current code:

```
mixed_anova <- ezANOVA(data = dat, 
                          dv = groups, 
                          wid = codes, 
                          within = c(test1, test2), 
                          detailed = TRUE) 

,,,


Thank you for any help!
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.